# You don't have permission to browse the server?

Tags: php, codeigniter, ckeditor, kcfinder

I am using kcfinder with ckeditor. While changing `disabled to false` in config file of kcfinder there is no problem but on overriding it with

```
$_SESSION['KCFINDER'] = array(
    'disabled' => false
);
```

i am unable to browse & upload files there.Message pop up's showing you don't have permission to browse the server.
(framework used CI 3.x.)

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13760367/kcfinder-you-do-not-have-permission-to-list-the-files?rq=1)

Comment: Possible duplicate of:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13760367/kcfinder-you-do-not-have-permission-to-list-the-files?rq=1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this. Make following changes to main index.php file

```
//$system_path = 'system';
$system_path = dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'system';
//$application_folder = 'application';
$application_folder = dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'application';
```

And put this code in browse.php of kcfinder

```
ob_start();
require_once('../index.php'); //path to main index file edited above
ob_end_clean();
$CI =& get_instance();
$CI->load->library('session');
```