# Looking for clarification of an an answer for a kcfinder issue

Tags: php, ckeditor, kcfinder

I understand this is a duplicate question of [You don't have permission to browse the server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40652833/you-dont-have-permission-to-browse-the-server)

However I am new to this, and am not a developer...I am just trying to keep the lights on during COVID.

I am not sure how to ask for clarification of the accepted answer...

> Make following changes to main index.php file

Question 1) Does "main" mean of the entire site? or of ckeditor?

```
//$system_path = 'system';
$system_path = dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'system';
//$application_folder = 'application';
$application_folder = dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'application';
```

Do I need to populate the specific directory on my server...or do I copy and paste exactly as is?

To clarify my situation, everything was working, we use session controls, simply editing the config file to "false" (aware of security risk) doesn't work.

I edited the browse.php file no problem as described and it helps, although I get a the following error messages

> Warning: require_once(../index.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/oscevents/public_html/framework/public/js/kcfinder/browse.php on line 16

> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '../index.php' (include_path='.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/share/pear') in /home/oscevents/public_html/framework/public/js/kcfinder/browse.php on line 16"

My apologies if I am not following protocols in anyway, just really need some guidance.