# ckeditor with kcfinder - HTTP Error 404.3 Not Found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ckeditor, kcfinder

I'm developing Application in ASP.NET MVC and wants to upload image from local PC into ckeditor. For that i've used kcfinder to browse image from computer and upload to server as well as ckeditor. after download kcfinder in my code, i've used following script in config.js:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = '/Scripts/ckeditor/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=files';
    config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = '/Scripts/ckeditor/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=images';
    config.filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl = '/Scripts/ckeditor/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=flash';
    config.filebrowserUploadUrl = '/Scripts/ckeditor/kcfinder/upload.php?opener=ckeditor&type=files';
    config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl = '/Scripts/ckeditor/kcfinder/upload.php?opener=ckeditor&type=images';
    config.filebrowserFlashUploadUrl = '/Scripts/ckeditor/kcfinder/upload.php?opener=ckeditor&type=flash';
};
```

After integrating code, i got the button in ckeditor for "Browse server". After clicking button, new window should open to show uploaded images. instead of that, browser showing me following error:

[image]

Path is correct but It seems like I'm missing something. help me out to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved.
when i uploaded code on live server, same was working fine.

If you are facing permission issue while browsing image than you have to follow this steps:

[KCFinder 'You do not have permission to list the files.'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13760367/kcfinder-you-do-not-have-permission-to-list-the-files][1])

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the issue by changing Handler Mappings under IIS section of website.
Open IIS Manager --> Handler Mappings. 
At the bottom you will find **StaticFile** handler. Just right click on **StaticFile** handler and select *Revert To Parent*. You will get a handler reset warning dialog, just click YES and the problem will be solved.

[image: IIS Handler Mappings]